# Entity Framework 6 Loading From DbContext Works But Same Load Doesn't Work In Context Wrapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I wrote a simple wrapper for my `DbContext` in order to add global exception handling on data queries without having to duplicate the handling on every query.  In doing so, I ran into an issues that I can't seem to wrap my head around why the query works loading directly from the `DbContext` but not the wrapper.  The wrapper throws an `System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException` with the inner exception `There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.`.  The thing I really don't understand is when I step through the code slowly, it works.  I mimicked the way the wrapper would load the query, but I'm seeing different results.  I'm sure I'm missing something very simple here, but I've been looking at this problem too long and am stuck trying the same things over and over.

I wrote out a Simple Self-Contained Example Program in order to demonstrate:

```
public class DataReaderTest
{
    public void Begin()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<Context>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<Context>());

        // create some objects in the database
        using (Context context = new Context())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Category c = new Category();
                c.Boards = new List<Board>();

                for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
                {
                    Board b = new Board();
                    b.Threads = new List<Thread>();
                    c.Boards.Add(b);

                    for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
                    {
                        Thread t = new Thread();
                        t.Posts = new List<Post>();
                        b.Threads.Add(t);

                        for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
                        {
                            Post p = new Post();
                            t.Posts.Add(p);
                        }
                    }
                }

                context.Categorys.Add(c);
            }

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        // use the context to query - works
        using (Context context = new Context())
        {
            // get all categories in the same fasion the helper does
            var categories = context.Set<Category>().Where(c => true).ToList();

            foreach (Category c in categories)
            {
                // from the categories, loop through the boards to get the earliest post associated
                foreach (Board b in c.Boards)
                {
                    // get the earliest post from any thread in the board in the same fasion the helper does
                    var post = context.Set<Post>().Where(p => p.Thread.BoardID == b.PrimaryKey).OrderBy(p => p.PrimaryKey).First();

                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Earliest post for Board {0}: {1}", b.PrimaryKey, post.PrimaryKey));
                }
            }
        }

        // use the ContextHelper to query - doesn't work
        using (ContextHelper helper = new ContextHelper())
        {
            // get all categories
            var categories = helper.Where<Category>(c => true).ToList();

            foreach (Category c in categories)
            {
                // from the categories, loop through the boards to get the earliest post associated
                foreach (Board b in c.Boards)
                {
                    // get the earliest post from any thread in the board
                    // this is where the error happens
                    var post = helper.Where<Post>(p => p.Thread.BoardID == b.PrimaryKey).OrderBy(p => p.PrimaryKey).First();

                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Earliest post for Board {0}: {1}", b.PrimaryKey, post.PrimaryKey));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// A simple wrapper around the DbContext
public class ContextHelper : IDisposable
{
    private Context _Context;

    public ContextHelper()
    {
        _Context = new Context();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(Func<T, bool> predicate) where T : class
    {
        return _Context.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _Context.Dispose();
        _Context = null;
    }
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
        : base("DefaultConnection") { }
    public DbSet<Category> Categorys { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Board> Boards { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Thread> Threads { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

[Table("Category")]
public class Category
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PrimaryKey { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Board> Boards { get; set; }
}

[Table("Board")]
public class Board
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PrimaryKey { get; set; }
    [Required, ForeignKey("Category")]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Thread> Threads { get; set; }
}

[Table("Thread")]
public class Thread
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PrimaryKey { get; set; }
    [Required, ForeignKey("Board")]
    public int BoardID { get; set; }
    public virtual Board Board { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

[Table("Post")]
public class Post
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PrimaryKey { get; set; }
    [Required, ForeignKey("Thread")]
    public int ThreadID { get; set; }
    public virtual Thread Thread { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This code works for me using Entity Framework 6.0.1 .Net 4.5 in a console app. What version/framework are you using?

Comment: .NET 4.5 with Entity Framework 6.0.2.  It will work if I have MultipleActiveResultSets=true as part of the connection string; however, I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: I removed the MultipleActiveResultSets=true to begin with and it worked for me. I thought that might have been the problem in the first place... I was using SQL 2012 (named instance) BTW..

Comment: I'm using SQL 2012 (named instance) as well.  I'm baffled now, so you get 2 sets of results when you run it?  I only get 1 set of results and then the exception.

Comment: Yes it runs fine and prints out Board 1-9 twice

Comment: I just updated to EF 6.0.2 and now get the same exception. Connection string does not have MultipleActiveResultSets=true in it. What has changed in the EF framework and is the correct behaviour now?

Comment: I'm relieved you're results are consistent with mine now, I can rule out computer issue. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44460/discussion-between-mark-and-middas)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try changing your wrapper where clause to be the same as what is happening in the DbContext: like this.

```
public IQueryable<T> Where<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class 
{ 
    return _Context.Set<T>().AsQueryable().Where(predicate); 
}
```

Where you are actually returning IQueryable and accepting an expression as an argument. I've just tested this and it seems to work.